# My Shiny App won't output more than one chart

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

My Shiny App won't output more than one chart. My code should be outputting five donut charts when I run my shiny app - the counts dataframe has five rows, but it's only outputting a donut chart for the final row.

[Part 1 of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO5aO.png)

[Part 2 of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxRjk.png)

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: Can you get the five plots outside Shiny?

Comment: @stephanelaurent yes! when I print the donut_charts list in rmarkdown, all of the five plots show up. I tried to use the subplot function to print plot_ly in shiny but when I use that, only one chart shows up

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try to set `height="auto"` in `plotlyOutput`.